# Java thread InterruptExceptioon handling stopped further code from being executed only in some situation

Tags: java, multithreading, java-11

the following short sample code illustrated the behavior that I couldn't explain

```
    ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Double> testQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
    
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        long cnt = 0;
        try {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                testQueue.add(Math.random());
                cnt++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("inner interrupted inserted %d record", cnt));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("interrupted inserted %d record", cnt));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("inserted %d record", cnt));
    });
```

If I called `t.interrupt()` to interrupt the thread

the expected behavior is 2 printed line that says:

```
inner interrupted inserted %d record
inserted %d record
```

where %d is replaced with corresponding value.

but the actual result is

```
inner interrupted inserted %d record
```

if we remove the inner catch to the Thread

```
    ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Double> testQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
    
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        long cnt = 0;
        try {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                testQueue.add(Math.random());
                cnt++;
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("interrupted inserted %d record", cnt));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("inserted %d record", cnt));
    });
```

then we get the output

```
interrupted inserted %d record
inserted %d record
```

as expected, as now the outer catch is catching the InterruptException

However, if instead I placed break in the inner most catch of the first code sample like so:

```
    ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Double> testQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
    
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        long cnt = 0;
        try {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                testQueue.add(Math.random());
                cnt++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("inner interrupted inserted %d record", cnt));
                    break; //this one
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("interrupted inserted %d record", cnt));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("inserted %d record", cnt));
    });
```

the expected behavior is produced.

why would the placement of the catch block create such difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [`Thread#interrupt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()):

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of [...] sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), [...], then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException.

> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt status will be set.

That means that in your examples either `Thread#sleep` throws the exception XOR `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` gives you true.

So in your first example you catch the exception, do the print and enter/stay in the infinite loop as `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` is always `false`.

In your second example the try-catch is not nested within the loop, so both prints happen and the thread terminates as expected.

In your third example you just explicitly exit the loop.

---

*FYI:* You don't neet to write `System.out.println(String.format(...))`. There is `System.out.printf`, but don't forget the `\n`.

Comment: when I inserted print statement at beginning of the loop, it showed the exact situation you have described. The loop kept going and did not terminate the thread